# Session Variables active for 4hours even after closing browser asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have Password recovery page where in I'm attempting to store user password recovery attempts. Here are my scenarios:

1. Maximum attempts per user in 4 hours is 5. After 3 attempts if user closes the browser and again reopens then his attempts should be 2. It can be tracked if we store in db. Instead I want to know is it possible with session variables?

I know session variables will reset if we close and open browser. Is there any way we can retain it for specified time programatically?

Note: Password recovery count should not reset even after clearing cache from browser.

Comment: Think about how a session gets associated with a particular user, and you'll see this isn't going to work. Instead, you should store the number of attempts in the database on the account that access is being attempted on.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to accomplish that using sessions. If you want to do such thing using client side you should do a research about cookies, otherwise keep using your DB for such validation.

Comment: okay thank you all. Using db to store attempts.